# ffmpeg concatenating videos of different fps while keeping the total length not changed

Tags: python, encoding, ffmpeg, mp4, frame-rate

I wanna pad an `mp4` video stream with another video clip of a static image that I created using:

```
def generate_white_vid (duration):
    output_filename = os.path.join(p_path,'white_vid_'+" 0:.2f}".format(duration)+'.mp4')
    ffmpeg_create_vid_from_static_img = 'ffmpeg -loop 1 -i /path/WhiteBackground.jpg -c:v libx264 -t %f -pix_fmt yuv420p -vf scale=1920:1080 %s' % (duration, output_filename)
    p = subprocess.Popen(ffmpeg_create_vid_from_static_img, shell=True)
    p.communicate()
    return output_filename
```

I use the following to concatenate:

```
def concat_vids(clip_paths):
    filenames_txt = open('clips_to_join.txt','w')
    for clip in clip_paths:
        filenames_txt.write ('file \''+ clip+'\'\n')
    filenames_txt.close()
    output_filename = clip_paths[0].split('.', 2)[0]
    output_file_path = os.path.join(root_path, output_filename+'-padded.mp4')
    # join the clips
    ffmpeg_command = ["ffmpeg", "-f", "concat", "-safe", "0", "-i", "clips_to_join.txt", "-codec", "copy", output_file_path] # output_filename = ch0X-start_time-end_time
    p = subprocess.Popen(ffmpeg_command)
    p.communicate() # wait till the subprocess finishes. You can send commands to process as well.
    return output_file_path
```

When I check the length of the resulting video after concatenation, I find that it is not equal to the sum of the two segments that I concatenated, and sometimes it is even less by some seconds!!

Here is how I get the video length in seconds:

```
def ffmpeg_len(vid_path):
    '''
    Returns length in seconds using ffmpeg
    '''
    ffmpeg_get_mediafile_length = ['sh', '-c', 'ffmpeg -i "$1" 2>&1 | grep Duration', '_', vid_path]
    p = subprocess.Popen(ffmpeg_get_mediafile_length, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)    
    output, err = p.communicate()
    length_regexp = 'Duration: (\d{2}):(\d{2}):(\d{2})(\.\d+),'
    re_length = re.compile(length_regexp)
    matches = re_length.search(output)
    if matches:
        video_length = int(matches.group(1)) * 3600 + \
                        int(matches.group(2)) * 60 + \
                        int(matches.group(3)) + float(matches.group(4))
        return video_length
    else:
        print("Can't determine video length.")
        print err
        raise SystemExit
```

My guess is that maybe the concatenation unifies the `fps` rate for the all the clips to be joined, if this is the case, how to prevent this from happening? How can I get a video of the desired length exactly.

Maybe it worth mentioning that the video to padded is very short `0.42 second`, the original video is `210.58` and the resultant video is `210.56`!

I have verified that ffmpeg does generate the desired padding region and it is of the desired length ~`0.42` I got a 0.43 segment when I forced `30 fps` but it is okay.

Comment: 1. I didn't parse your Python code. To make it easier for lazy answerers you should separate the Python code from the ffmpeg command and confirm if the issue is due to one or the other. Run ffmpeg manually, unscripted and see if you can reproduce the issue. 2. Show the actual ffmpeg command generated by `ffmpeg_create_vid_from_static_img` and its console output. Show info of other vid. 3. Don't machine parse the ffmpeg console output to get duration: the format is not standardized and is therefore fragile for processing. [Use ffprobe instead](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/FFprobeTips#Duration).

Comment: Thank you for your comment. `ffprobe` gives the same length as `ffmpeg` on the result file and I have verified that the problem is not coming from the white padding segment, I checked its length and it was as expected